# how to deal with int overflow in php

Tags: php, int, overflow

I am trying to execute below expression in php

```
pow(26, 36357)
```

It is showing incorrect output due to very long integer value. 
How to deal with it and get the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `gmp_pow()` functions if you have gmp extension enabled or `bcpow()` if you have bc_math extension enabled.

```
$a = gmp_pow(26, 36357);
```

or,

```
$a = bcpow(26, 36357);
```

[gmp_pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-pow.php), [bcpow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php)